# How do I make compilation stop nicely if a constant is used in my source file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to test for the use of a constant in a source file and if it is used, stop compilation.

The constant in question is defined in a generic driver file which a number of driver implementations inherit from.  However, it's use has been deprecated so subsequent updates to each drivers should switch to using a new method call and not the use of this const value.

This doesn't work obviously

```
#ifdef CONST_VAR
#error "custom message"
#endif
```

How can I do this elegantly?  As It's an int, I can define CONST_VAR as a string and let it fail, but that might make it difficult for developers to understand what actually went wrong.  I was hoping for a nice #error type message.

Any suggestions?

---

The Poison answer here is excellent.  However for older versions of VC++ which don't support [[deprecated]] I found the following works.

Use `[[deprecated]]` (C++14 compilers) or `__declspec(deprecated)`

To treat this warning as an error in a compilation unit, put the following pragma near the top of the source file.

`#pragma warning(error: 4996)`

e.g.

```
const int __declspec(deprecated) CLEAR_SOURCE = 0;
const int __declspec(deprecated("Use of this constant is deprecated. Use ClearFunc() instead. See: foobar.h"));
```

Comment: Can you provide some background on what you're trying to do here? While this might be the right way to approach this, something about this makes me suspect there might be a different, easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why does the snippet above not work?

Comment: @Tas It unconditionally aborts compilation regardless of whether the deprecated constant is actually used in the source code.

Comment: Is it possible to declare the constant with the `[[deprecated]]` attribute?

Comment: @L.F. in VC++ I was able to do that with const int __declspec(deprecated) MYCONST = 0;

Comment: @Matt You can use `[[deprecated]] int MYCONST = 0;` on any compiler that supports C++14.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks.  I'm using a mixture of Visual Studio 2019 and 2008.  The driver compiles under both versions.  I'm stuck with 2008 until the embedded WinCE 6.0 target is removed.  We have some old hardware here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no standard way to do this, but gcc and clang's preprocessors have [`#pragma poison`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) which allows you to do just that -- you declare certain preprocessor tokens (identifiers, macros) as poisoned and if they're encountered while preprocessing, compilation aborts.

```
#define foo
#pragma GCC poison printf sprintf fprintf foo
int main()
{
  sprintf(some_string, "hello"); //aborts compilation
  foo; //ditto
}
```

For warnings/errors after preprocessing, you can use C++14's [[[deprecated]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated) attribute, whose warnings you can turn into errors with clang/gcc's `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` .

```
int foo [[deprecated]];
[[deprecated]] int bar ();

int main()
{
    return bar()+foo;
}
```

This second approach obviously won't work for on preprocessor macros.

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  I am using VC++.  The poison/deprecated keywords helped me locate this link for VC++.  The Best Answer section is gold.  https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190306/13628.html.  You might want to include that in your answer.